# How to enable working FocusState with UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, uihostingcontroller

In out project we use SwiftUI as View layer working with UIKit for navigation.
When view created with UIHostingController TextFields don't reacts to @FocusState property wrapper. If create similar example as on screenshot in full SwiftUI project @FocusState will work.

```
@FocusState var isFocused: Bool

@ViewBuilder
func phoneTextField() -> some View {
    TextField("",
              text: $viewModel.phoneTextfieldNumber,
              prompt: Text("Введите номер")
        .foregroundColor(Resources.Colors.textDark.swiftUIColor)
        .font(Fonts.Gilroy.semiBold.swiftUIFont(size: 16)))
    .textFieldStyle(PhoneNumberTextFieldStyleTest())
    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
    .background(isFocused ? .clear : Resources.Colors.backgroundGrey100.swiftUIColor)
    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
    .cornerRadius(12)
    .overlay(content: {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
            .stroke(Resources.Colors.buttonRed100.swiftUIColor, lineWidth: isFocused ? 2 : 0)
    })
    .focused($isFocused)
    .animation(.default, value: isFocused)
    .onChange(of: isFocused, perform: { newValue in
        print("NEWFOCUS", newValue)
    })
}
```

I try to wrap TextField into Button and it's work to change appearance, but we can focus TextField programmatically with this method

```
struct FocusedTextField: View {

var placeholder: String
@Binding var text: String
@State private var isFocused: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    Button {
        isFocused = true
    } label: {
        TextField("",
                  text: $text,
                  prompt: Text(placeholder)
            .foregroundColor(Resources.Colors.textDark.swiftUIColor)
            .font(Fonts.Gilroy.semiBold.swiftUIFont(size: 16)))
        .textFieldStyle(PhoneNumberTextFieldStyle(isFocused: $isFocused))
        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
    .background(isFocused ? .clear : Resources.Colors.backgroundGrey100.swiftUIColor)
    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
    .cornerRadius(12)
    .overlay(content: {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
            .stroke(Resources.Colors.buttonRed100.swiftUIColor, lineWidth: isFocused ? 2 : 0)
    })
    .animation(.default, value: isFocused)
    .buttonStyle(NoneAnimateStyle())
}
}
```

**UPD:** Focus state brokes only when UIHostingController is part of UINavigationController

Comment: please add code here. Don't use image.